# Android system app to enable programmatic ethernet tethering

Tags: android, kotlin

Starting with Android 11, devices with ethernet and WiFi hardware may offer ethernet tethering, where the device may share an internet connection through WiFi with devices plugged into the ethernet.

And it works reasonably well.  All devices on the ethernet have access to the internet through the WiFi.

However, if you're developing a kiosk app in Android, and you have specialized devices that it needs to communicate with over the ethernet, but you also need internet access, you must ask the user to enable ethernet tethering to access those specialized devices.

This leads to confusion for the end user.

To work around this, I want the app to enable ethernet tethering programmatically, so we don't have to beg and pester the user to do this.

But, unfortunately for my scenario, Android doesn't provide an app with a way to do this unless that app is a "System" app, as this is the only kind of app that can gain the appropriate permissions necessary to do this.

So... I need to build a System app to provide to our vendor.

How?  Is there some place where I can relatively easy pull together:

- An environment to develop this system app
- A way to test this system app (virtualized device is just fine)

So far, everything I've read feels like one has to become a full blown Embedded Android developer, and while that would be fun, it seems like a bit much for what I am attempting to do here.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd be of much help, but if the specialized device you speak of is a kitchen printer, I've not heard of that done. My team works with WiFi-capable kitchen printers for the purpose, typically requiring us to configure a static IP for them on the network, so we give the merchant a lightweight router configured by us to ensure that is the case.

Assuming you have control over device distribution, system apps are just regular apps installed in `/system/app`. A normal user can't access that directory, but you could root the devices. Many sources say it is ROM, but it is not.

Comment: Heh... I subscribe to the idea that something nobody has done is worth doing if it solves a problem, so I don't fear the unknown in this field.  From what I've studied, and what dr_g mentions in his answer, the app needs to be signed, which can be tricky in this situation, but I'll see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck! It's not as complicated as you might fear.

In terms of the app itself, the source code and how it is built and tested can be exactly the same. You can write, compile and test your app in Android Studio, just the same if you are used to using that IDE.

But you don't have to either. Traditionally, the system and platform apps are developed using .mk build files and ninja. But that is another story. Pre-built apk (and aar, jar) files can be pre-installed in the system too.

The main difference in what the app can do, is the permissions you might be wanting to bestow on the app, and which are granted at install time or runtime, or not. Whether that happens is done in two ways: how it is signed (i.e. with the platform key), or where it is installed into the file-system of your vendor's system (e.g. /system/priv-app).

From your question, you're probably wanting to grant the `android.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED` permission, reserved for system apps, I assume.

To test your app, you need to have access to your vendor's platform key. Before installing you must sign (and align) the app with that key. Then install the app as usual via adb. When your app is ready, the vendors can take care of putting it in the right place on the system, as part of the official image.

Comment: The vendor works with many other folks than us, but maybe they'll provide a vendor key that's specific to us or something, so I can look into that.  And, yes, I'm looking to use the android.permission.TETHER_PRIVILEGED permission.

Comment: To set up something like a test environment for yourself (but not the official vendor platform), you can launch a virtual device that you know the platform key for, and sign your app with that platform key. You're not testing on the same platform so some system interactions may change, but this should still provide some useful early results that the permissions are being provided and the tethering features you want, are working :-) See here for keys: https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_build/tree/master/target/product/security

Comment: I'm going to mark this as the answer, as I managed to get this approach to work (my vendor did kindly provide keys).  Now, if only I could get my app to work for purpose.

Comment: For anyone else viewing this question... to update the app afterwards, you need to adb shell rm the file, adb push it again, and adb install it.  Why, I am not sure.

Comment: "if only I could get my app to work for purpose" hehe, down to the nitty gritty now, good luck!